# Comments for Content Types

Tags: 2010, content-type, list-item

One piece of functionality I thought was oddly unincluded in SharePoint 2010 was the ability to create comment trails for content types other than blog posts and to a lesser extent discussion boards.

I'm working on a SharePoint server where several custom content types built could benefit from comment trails. So far online I've only found semi-solutions to this problem. I've found solutions that allow a user to post a comment once (which is why I keep using the phrase comment trail, so that people can respond back to each other) and a solution that creates an associated list that tracks the content type's ID and does commenting that way.

While I'm not knocking those solutions, they really aren't scalable (I'd have to create several associated lists) nor do I think they'd work well with search.

Has anyone come across a solution that adds commenting to non-OOB content types with comments? Paid or free -- I would just like to see if anyone has found a better way to do this than my current best answer of creating several associated lists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for:

A multi line text field with option: "Append Changes to Existing Text" does not work for you?

UPDATE:
Based on your comments, I think you are looking for a full comments and rich functionality. Check out solution below:

http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2011/09/04/customizing-listitem-forms-using-renderingtemplates/

Comment: I don't think that's the same as comments, is it? I'm looking for something like the commments ability of a blog for other content types like a list so users could post comments about a list item. For instance, if someone uploads a screenplay document, I would like other users to be able to comment on it. I just found out about the SocialCommentControl but is there anyway to utilize search with this control (as in, where the heck is it stored and linked to the item being commented on!?!)

Comment: OK, I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome -- this is an extension of where my research has led me (I don't mean to sound rude or condicending here I just want to let you know I'm not doing any work on my side) and looks like the best option I'm going to have. My one question is if you know if Search integrates with the SocialCommentsControl so that if users search a comment on a list item, they'd be taken to the list item.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure about that because the comments would be stored in social database and not a list item data like list columns/fields. If it was on a web page, the comments would get crawled but I have doubts over list items

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2011/06/12/custom-note-board-web-part-socialcommentmanager-social-security-trimming-and-search.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much for your help (I'll read over that link in a bit). I'm in the right direction now, and thanks for clarifying a bunch of points for me (and some very useful links).

Comment: For reference, if anyone is looking to implement a Stack Overflow kind of voting system, here is a good link to get started: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=438 It's not exactly what I'm talking about here, but it's another option we're entertaining for another part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available out of the box but fairly easy achieved using a custom list to store the comments in and a lookup column to the list holding the items to be commented on. Users can then add items (comments) in that custom list and select the item they are commenting on in the lookup column drop down.

To show the comments about a certain item, add 2 listview webparts on a page and bind them the top 1 to the source list and the bottom 1 to the comments list. Create a connection between the 2 webparts and have the top 1 act as a filter on the webpart showing the comments